# C# Unique ID for tcp/ip server client connection

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

below is roughly how I normally do when trying to setup a connection on my server with my slient device:

```
IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, nConst3rdPartyPort);
the3rdPartyListener = new Socket(localEP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
the3rdPartyListener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
the3rdPartyListener.Bind(localEP);
the3rdPartyListener.Listen(100);
the3rdPartyListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnectBack), the3rdPartyListener);
```

Any client device can connect to my server if they know the server ip and port number.
Now, I want to do filtering of client device. Only specific client device can connect to my server.

Is it that we can insert a unique ID to client so that the client with only that unique ID can connect to my server? 
How do we ensure that the client is the specific client that we want?

This is for security reason to prevent unauthorized client from connecting to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IPEndPoint` Address method to retrieve the remote IPAddress and make a whitelist to check who can connect your server.

```
string clientIP = ((IPEndPoint)(the3rdPartyListener.RemoteEndPoint)).Address.ToString();
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Updated:
I'm not sure Csharp Socket has verified device method or not. But I have a method on below.
Use `NetworkStream` to pass data from Client to Server that verified the client.

Server Side:

```
TcpClient client;
TcpListener server;
Thread thread;
Thread threadTwo;
byte[] datalength = new byte[4];

public Server()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2018);
    server.Start();
    thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        ServerReceive();
    }
    thread.Start();
}

void ServerReceive()
{
    networkStream = client.GetStream();
    threadTwo = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while ((i = networkStream.Read(datalength, 0, 4)) != 0)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(datalength, 0)];
            networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                if(Encoding.Default.GetString(data) == "unique ID")
                {
                    //Do your job
                }
            }
        }
    }
    threadTwo.Start();
}
```

Client Side:

```
NetworkStream networkStream;
TcpClient client;
byte[] datalength = new byte[4];

public Client()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    try
    {
        client = new TcpClient("your server ip", 2018);
        ClientSend("unique ID");
    }
     catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

void ClientSend(string msg)
{
    try
    {
        networkStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] data;
        data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg);
        int length = data.Length;
        byte[] datalength = new byte[4];
        datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
        networkStream.Write(datalength, 0, 4);
        networkStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oliver, thanks for the comment. But is there a method like pairing for bluetooth where there is a unique id involve?

Comment: Oliver, I'm afraid that once the unauthorized client know the whitelist IP that we used, then it can connect already.. Is there a method like client have to give a unique id to server, and if the unique id matches with the server, then it can connect.

Comment: @Coolguy The client must connect to your server before sending the data to your server and I also updated my answer.

Comment: Oliver, I appreciate your answer. But what if the client doesn't send any unique id? What if the client just connect and listen to server anonymously.. I don't want this to happen. Is it we have to set some kind of timer for client to send the id. If the server doesn't received the id within a period of time, then it will disconnect the client.